# Using %ERRORLEVEL% to return a value from subroutine in batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, subroutine, errorlevel

I've been echoing my way through the following code but I cannot determine why `%ERRORLEVEL%` is **always** zero.

```bat
@echo off

set activePerl_SiteBinPath=D:\ProgramFiles\ActivePerl\site\bin
call :isInPath %activePerl_SiteBinPath% & set foundActivePerl_SiteBinPath=%ERRORLEVEL%
echo %foundActivePerl_SiteBinPath%

set blub=d:\blub
call :isInPath %blub% & set foundBlub=%ERRORLEVEL%
echo %foundBlub%
exit /b

:isInPath
::  Tests if the path stored within variable pathVar exists within %PATH%.
::
::  The result is returned as the ERRORLEVEL:
::      0 if pathVar is found in %PATH%.
::      1 if pathVar path is not found in %PATH%.
::      2 if parhVar path is missing/undefined.

:: Error checking
if "%~1"=="" exit /b 2

set pathVar=%~1
for /f %%i in ('echo ";%%PATH%%;" ^| find /c /i ";%pathVar%;"') do (
    set /a foundPathVar=%%i
)
if /i %foundPathVar% equ 0 (
    exit /b 1
)
set foundPathVar=0
exit /b 0
```

I get the following output

```
0
0
```

but I would expect

```
0
1
```

and according to the echoing I did inside `:isInPath` for case one `exit /b 0` and for case two `exit /b 1` is called. But why is `%ERRORLEVEL%` zero in **both** cases? I totally don't get it. Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cmd the whole line will be parsed for variable substitution at once. Hence at the time the following line is executed `errorlevel` is 0

```bat
call :isInPath %blub% & set foundBlub=%ERRORLEVEL%
```

You need to use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

```bat
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
call :isInPath %blub% & set foundBlub=!ERRORLEVEL!
```

Comment: simply splitting the line into two should solve the problem without delayed expansion

Comment: @Stephan that would be too obvious